# swift UIButton click unavailable out of tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift4

the following code, click event works.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "SwiftCell")

    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(hiddenGear ? "+" : "-", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.toggleGear), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 36, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    cell.addSubview(button)
```

[image]

but what i want just like below:

[image]

move UIButton out of the **uitableview cell**, and the click event does not work.

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width - 36, y: -30, width: 30, height: 30)
```

try to use `cell.bringSubview(toFront: button)` , but it does not work too. have any idea?

Comment: where you add this code ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is illegal:

```
cell.addSubview(button)
```

You may not add a view to the cell. You must add the view only to the cell's `contentView`.

But the content view does not extend all the way to the right. If you want the view all the way over at the right, you must provide it as an accessory view.

Finally, you cannot easily add a working button outside the cell bounds, because a subview outside its superview's bounds is not touchable. You can make it touchable, however, by munging the hit-testing for the superview. You would need to override this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

Answer (score 0):

You need to use constraints, relative to the top of that `UITableViewCell`. Also, I can see you are trying to create a '+' (plus) icon in the corner. Consider using a `Navigation Item` found in the Object Library.

Answer (score 0):

First it's not preferred to add UI elements inside cellForRow because of reusing , second you can encapsulate the button inside the cell and play with the background color to fake that it's out of cell if the button is supposed to be in every cell , otherwise you have to add it relative to the mainView (self.view)